# MGF technique for exponential / Chisquared

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, moment-generating-function

Let $X$, $U$, $V$, $W$, $Y$ be independent exponential random variables with respective means
$\frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{3}, 1, \frac{2}{3}$. Use the variables $X, U, V, W, Y$ to construct a variable having an $F$ distribution with $(3,2)$ degrees of freedom.

The issue here is that no matter what I do, I can't get a Chi-squared with an odd degrees of freedom. For example, $12X$ will be $\chi^2_2$. Same for $4U$. To get an $F_{(3,2)}$, we need a $\chi^2_3$ divided by its df, over a $\chi^2_2$ divided by its df.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint: there are [close connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Relation_to_other_distributions) between chi-squared (or, equivalently, Gamma) distributions and Beta distributions. F distributions [can be obtained from Beta distributions,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution#Related_distributions_and_properties) too.

Comment: @whuber Will those relationships actually get there? It's possible I am being especially dense.

Comment: I can see *a* way to do it, but it's complicated enough that I am sure there must be a much simpler way.

Comment: @Glen_b You're right; I had lost track of the factors of $1/2$.  I suspect the person who made up this question might themselves have been confused and really wanted to ask how to create an $F(6,4)$ distribution from these five variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exponential distributions are rescaled $\chi^2(2)$ distributions.  Let's assume the scaling has been reversed (which is done *via* a constant multiplication) and all means are equal to $2$.

One solution starts by generating a scaled $\chi^2(1)$ variate $A$ from two independent $\chi^2(2)$ variates $U$ and $V$ via

$$A = U\left(\cos(2\pi\exp(-V/2))\right)^2.$$

This is equivalent to the [Box-Mueller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform), which is a well-known way of generating a pair of (independent) standard normal variates from two independent uniform variates.  One of those normals, when squared, equals $A$ and therefore has a $\chi^2(1)$ distribution.

The rest is easy given two more independent exponential variates $W$ and $Y$: $W+A$ has a $\chi^2(3)$ distribution and $Y$ independently has a $\chi^2(2)$ distribution, whence (practically from [the definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution#Related_distributions_and_properties) of $F$ as a ratio of scaled $\chi^2$ variables) $$F=\frac{(W+A)/3}{Y/2} = \frac{2}{3}\frac{W+U\cos^2(2\pi e^{-V/2})}{Y}$$ does the trick.

Note that only four of the five exponential variables are needed.

---

Here is `R` code comparing $100,000$ realizations of $F$ to corresponding quantiles of the $F(3,2)$ distribution:

```r
n <- 1e5
set.seed(17)
v <- matrix(rgamma(4*n, 1, scale=2), ncol=4)
a <- v[, 1] * cos(2*pi*exp(-v[, 2]/2))^2 
x <- v[, 3] + a
y <- v[, 4]
f <- 2*x/(3*y)

f.q <- qf((1:n - 1/2)/n, 3,2)
plot(f.q, sort(f), log="xy", pch=19, cex=0.5,
     xlab="F quantile", ylab="Data",
     main="F probability plot")
abline(c(0,1), col="Blue", lwd=2)
```

The probability plot shows a close correspondence:

[image: F probability plot]

As a double-check, we can verify that `a`, `y`, and `x` average close to their expectations of $1$, $2$, and $3$ respectively:

```
> mean(a)
[1] 0.9948789
> mean(x)
[1] 3.003484
> mean(y)
[1] 1.986864
```

Finally, probability plots confirm that `a`, `y`, and `x` appear to have $\chi^2$ distributions with the desired degrees of freedom (and correct scales):

```r
pp <- function(x, df, ...) {
  x.q <- qchisq((1:n - 1/2)/n, df)
  plot(x.q, sort(x), 
       xlab="Quantile", ylab="Data",
       main=paste("Chi^2(", df, ") probability plot", sep=""), ...)
  abline(c(0,1), col="Red", lwd=2)
}
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
pp(a, 1, pch=19, cex=3/4)
pp(y, 2, pch=19, cex=3/4)
pp(x, 3, pch=19, cex=3/4)
```

[image]

By construction `x` and `y` are independent, so there's no need to test this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But I can't see how you got that formula for A. According to that wikipedia page the algorithm uses two standard uniforms. I tried the probability integral transform on U and V to get two uniforms but the formula looks different from yours.

Comment: It should be plausible from the checks I made that my formula is correct. To connect it to what you might be reading, notice that when $V$ has an exponential distribution of mean $\mu$, $\exp(-V/\mu)$ has a uniform distribution. The Box-Mueller components *when squared* both have the form of a $\chi^2(2)$ distribution times the squared cosine (or sine) of a uniform: that's exactly the formula for $A$ here. Whence $A$ is the square of a single Normal variate (of zero mean), showing it must be a constant multiple of a $\chi^2(1)$ variable. That its mean is $1$ shows the multiple is correct.

Comment: +1 This was indeed the solution I referred to when I commented above "*I can see a way to do it, but it's complicated enough that I am sure there must be a much simpler way.*".

Comment: Wow, I get it now. Thank you! Last thing I was wondering how you so easily knew that $exp(−V/μ)$ would be uniform. Is that because if we plug V into it's CDF we get a uniform, and then one minus that is also uniform?

Comment: The exponential function is the inverse cumulative distribution for the exponential distribution; thus $\exp(-V/\mu)$ is its [probability integral transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform). That, I think, is the crux of the matter: once you can fashion a combination of your input variables (exponentials) that can be transformed to a uniform distribution, then if you can do that *twice* (independently) you can create a standard Normal variable, whence by squaring it a $\chi^2(1)$ variable, and you're all set.

Comment: @Glen_b I was wondering what you meant by "complicated" and "much simpler." One way to assess complication is to add up (a) the number of independent variates and (b) the number of elementary arithmetical operations needed. "Elementary" may be subjective; let's say it's whatever your handheld (non-statistical) calculator can do. (I have assumed it includes exponential and trig functions.) My solution uses 4 variates and 10 operations = 14 total. *Any* solution requiring 5 variates needs at least 4 ops = 9 total. There doesn't seem to be much room between 14 and 9 for a "much simpler way"!

Comment: Simpler in the sense of '*obvious enough to a student that it has the correct properties that they might plausibly be expected to discover it for themselves without expert help, so it could be reasonably set as an exercise*'.

Comment: @Glen_b Ah...the distinction between discovering an answer and checking whether it is correct: one can be hard and the other easy.  I see what you mean now.  That is why I speculated that the formulator of this question (not the O.P, who is pondering it) was expecting an answer of the form $(\alpha U+\beta V+\gamma W)/(\xi X + \eta Y)$ (complexity=14 :-)), because the question is just begging for that kind of solution. Actually I posted my answer hoping it might inspire someone to improve upon it, because maybe we're all missing something obvious :-).

Comment: If the students had just seen the usual bivariate trick for showing the standard normal integrates to 1 (start with the product of two independent normal densities, convert to polar co-ordinates), *that* might just be enough of a clue for the more enterprising among them. I agree about the setup of the question suggesting that form of answer you mentioned.

Comment: (+1) Great answer. Am I right in assuming that you didn't use the random variables with the means as given by the OP in your answer? I just wondered because the question states that $V$ has a mean of $1/3$ which would mean that $\exp(-3V)$ has a uniform distribution, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @COOL Thank you.  I believe you may have read past the second sentence in my answer, which addresses the differing means.

Comment: Sorry again, but isn't the cumulative distribution of the exponential, $1-exp(-v/μ)$? Thus $1-exp(-V/μ)$ would be $U(0,1)$ and $1-(1-exp(-V/μ)) = exp(-V/μ)$ is also U(0,1). I thought that's how you got it. I just found it a bit confusing when you said "The exponential function is the inverse cumulative distribution for the exponential distribution". I thought the inverse of the cumulative distribution of the exp had a log in it. Thanks.

Comment: @abbey Sorry, you're right: I should not have included the word "inverse" there.